# How to redirect hostname to ec2 instance?

Tags: glassfish, amazon-ec2, hosting, glassfish-3, cloud-hosting

I have this domain 'suaparte.org' and I have the website running in a EC2 here http://50.19.242.172:8080/SuaParte/ I would like to redirect 'suaparte.org' to http://50.19.242.172:8080/SuaParte/.

Amazon provied a public dns to my elastic ip : ec2-50-19-242-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com

I think it's just put this public dns in my hostname provider, but I wonder, how he gonna know to redirect to http://50.19.242.172:8080/SuaParte/ ?
And not to other project that I have deployed in my glassfish ?

Answer (score 1):

DNS is a 'better' name for IP. Nothing more. With it you cannot specify port (in your case `8080`) or contextPath (in your case `SuaParte`).

To do that you must install a http server on port 80 (default port for http protocol) on your server. And than when accessing `http://50.19.242.172:80` will handle the redirect to http://50.19.242.172:8080/SuaParte/.

Other solution is to configure the `glassfish` to run on port 80 and then deploy your app as default (to contextPath `/`).

Answer (score 1):

This is a general web server question and is not specific to Amazon EC2.  It works pretty much the same there as on any other web server.

You have a couple options including:

1. Change your web server to be listening on port 80 of 50.19.242.172 and point your DNS for suaparte.org and www.suaparte.org to resolve to 50.19.242.172.  If you have multiple web sites on that server and that port, then you'll want to learn how to configure virtual hosts so that they each serve their own content depending on what hostname the browser is trying to access.  Once you have virtual hosts, you may want to simply show the home page at "/" or you can redirect to the "/SuaParte/" path.
2. Point DNS for suaparte.org and www.suaparte.org to a different web server (still running on port 80) that redirects the browser to port 8080, path /SuaParte/ on your EC2 box.  The most convenient solution here would be if your domain registrar or DNS provider allows you to set up a redirect for free.  You might find this under the DNS configuration settings of your provider.